# Where i can find Php.ini file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, phpeclipse

I am trying to upload an image in my PHP program using eclipse, but here i am not able to find php.ini file.

please help for this 
thank you

Comment: That depends on OS, which OS you are using?

Comment: i am using  Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can find your php.ini file regardless of what operating system you are using!

First make a new php file called info.php or some other file name, and deploy it to the document folder, with the following code in it:

```
<?php
  echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Then access that new php page through the web browser (if the server is working right, the URL is something like http://localhost/php.info maybe).

Then it shows a ton of info including the location of the php.info file.

For me it says "Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/fpm"  since I am using linux.

Also I think in Windows you can use a file find operation to locate your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks For your Response :-)

Answer (score 0):

open up your terminal / command line and enter in the following to find your php.ini file

```
php -i | grep /php.ini
```